# Store a value, adding 1 and use it in an insert using Db2

Tags: db2

I'm working on a Db2 database, the goal is to store the max value in the column T1PROG using the composite key (T1CATEGORIA, T1SEDE, T1CERTIFICATO), adding 1 and then insert the record in the same table.

I've tried quite few approaches at this problem and the "most working" solution I could find is this

```
CREATE VARIABLE t1prog CHAR;
CREATE VARIABLE result INT;
SELECT MAX(T1PROG) INTO t1prog FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE T1SEDE = 'abcd' AND T1CATEGORIA = 'abc' AND T1CERTIFICATO = 'numCertPe';
SELECT CAST(t1prog AS INT) INTO result;
SET result = result + 1;
SELECT CAST(result AS CHAR) INTO t1prog;
INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (T1CATEGORIA, T1SEDE, T1CERTIFICATO, T1PROG) VALUES ('abc','abcd','numCertPe',t1prog);
DROP VARIABLE t1prog;
DROP VARIABLE result;
```

but db2 does not recognize the keyword INTO and give me this error: (even though IBM documentation list SELECT INTO statement as valid)

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0109N  The statement or command was not processed because the following clause is not supported in the context where it is used: "INTO".

there's a cast because T1PROG is a char column
I cannot use functions or stored procedures or modify the DB.

EDIT.
I give a little extra context, this is a part of a already existing transaction which instructions cannot be modified, my goal is to make a piece of code that generate automatically the queries in db2 language by reading a bunch of data from a db and from a JSON.
I somehow managed to code all the necessary to create all the instructions but this part (take the max value, add one and put it back in a new record).
It's really driving me crazy.
I'm working on db2.core for luw

Comment: This strategy won't work for a multiuser app. It'll eventually produce collisions. It will work for a single user app, or for a batch process, though.

Comment: You can use `compound atomic` SQL, in an anonymous block (i.e. not a routine or sproc)  to submit a single statement. What is the meaning of adding 1 to a char column unless that char is proved to be 0 to 9 only ? You should code defensively for that, raise exception if needed. Also configure your tool (that submits the SQL) to support alternative statement delimiter to support compound sql.

Comment: What Db2 version and platform are you on? What product (version and platform) is the documentation for? What is the scenario? There are features to obtain increasing numbers (sequence, identity column, ...)